# ListView savedInstanceState not working well

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, arraylist

I have a ListView and when I add items I save that with:

```
static ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArrayList("notes", notes);
}
```

and in the onCreate I get it with:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    notes.add("Test");
} else {
    notes = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("notes");
}

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item, notes);
listView().setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

The notes are saving and that is everything okay except the savedInstanceState is null and when I start the app over again it adds "Test" every time, where is my mistake?

Comment: Saved instance is not persisted between two application starts. It is used only for preserving state during orientation change or pausing app while in background

Comment: @EugenMartynov thank you sir, any idea how to make that even when I start it over again?

Comment: Save to file, to shared preferences, to database

Comment: @EugenMartynov is right, and based on what you expect, you should rather use `SharedPreferences` - although this may require few tweaks to your current code to accommodate it. For instance, instead of ArrayList<String>, you could use `Set<String> notes = new HashSet<String>();` and cache this by calling `sharedPrefsEditor.putStringSet("notes", notes);`

Comment: As for me, shared preferences is only for small data like preferences. So for data itself I would use something more suitable. However shared preferences is easiest way to achieve it

Comment: Thank you guys both I knew about `SharedPreferences` I will try to figure it out..